# How to change the source of a physical file which has no DDS?

Tags: ibm-midrange

I want to add a new field to the physical file but it has not DDS.Only object is present in that library(lib1).source is in another library(call it lib2).I have made changes to file in lib2.how do I reflect these changes in lib1 without compiling and loss of data.

Answer (score 3):

All you need is:

```
CHGPF FILE(lib1/file) SRCFILE(lib2/qddssrc)
```

It will adjust the file, keeping any existing records, and also adjust any related logical files.  I would recompile programs that touch the files(s) to avoid level checks, or use "LVLCHK(*NO)" on the CHGPF command.

I assumed that because you changed the file in lib2, the source exists there and for an authority reason you can't copy to lib1.  If no source exists in lib2 there is this useful utility:

https://www.mcpressonline.com/programming-other/cl/retrieve-dds-source-for-a-physical-or-logical-file

Comment: Prefer recompiles

Answer (score -1):

how about using sql like

```
alter table library.file  
add column abc char(25) ccsid 37 not null default ''
```

then change level check to avoid compiling your program

```
CHGPF FILE(library/file) LVLCHK(*NO)
```

Comment: Bad idea to set `LVLCHK(*NO)`. There are only a few cases where this is safe. It is better to just recompile your programs.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy. i just answering his question. He want to add extra fields without DDS - add it using sql. He don't want to recompile - then set LVLCHK(*NO). From my experience, normally it is safe,  if you know how people program their program. He must always test related program to ensure its ok.

Comment: Given that it sounds like he does have DDS in another library, the use of ALTER TABLE (which certainly has its place, just not here I think) would mean he potentially ends up with DDS and object not matching, which sounds like a bad idea to me. I'm always a fan of people being told about CHGPF SRCFILE(...), anyway, it's a great piece of functionality which lots of people don't seem to get taught about.